# My vhost load the first enabled site for all my domain names

Tags: apache, debian, virtualhost, vhosts

I host multiple website on one debian 9 vps server with 3 different domain name.

1. first site --> /var/www/ecb
2. second site --> /var/www/shop
3. third site --> /var/www/site

I created a vhost file for each site. The problem is apache2 loads only the first enabled site.

Here is my vhost files

```
  Listen 80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.ecb.com
    ServerAlias *.ecb.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/ecb
    # Autres directives ici
  </VirtualHost>

  Listen 80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.shop.com
    ServerAlias *.shop.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/shop
    # Autres directives ici
  </VirtualHost>

  Listen 80
  <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.site.com
    ServerAlias *.site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/site
    # Autres directives ici
  </VirtualHost>
```

I have disabled the 000-default.conf

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://debian-administration.org/article/412/Hosting_multiple_websites_with_Apache2) might help. In it they used multiple files to host multiple sites.

Comment: Verify your logs, you probably have warnings / errors in there.  Ex `Listen 80` should not appear more than once on the same port.  If you are using Apache 2.2, you should have `NameVirtualHost` set.  In 2.4 it is done by default.  When apache does not know which VirtualHost to use, it responds with the first one it read.  Which is what you are getting.  Are the VirtualHost defined all in 1 file, or in many?  If many, make sure they are all included.  You should put `LogLevel debug` to see as much as possible in logs.  Bonne chance.

Comment: Thanks you Nic3500 it is working fine.